# Game of life Oscillators and Spaceships not working

Tags: java, algorithm, javafx

Hi so I am currently working on a game of life with javafx canvas. However there seems to be a bug in my algorithm. The still lifes are working however the rest is not, the patterns like the glider aren't moving the way they should. Im using a 2d int array, ALIVE is 1 and DEAD is 0.  Here is my algorithm:

```
    private void checkRules() {
        int[][] newBoard = board;
        int amountOfAliveNeighbours;
        for (int y = 0; y < board.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < board[y].length; x++) {
                amountOfAliveNeighbours = getAmountOfAliveNeighbours(x, y);
                if (board[y][x] == ALIVE) {
                    if (amountOfAliveNeighbours == 2 || amountOfAliveNeighbours == 3) {
                        newBoard[y][x] = ALIVE;
                    }else{
                        newBoard[y][x] = DEAD;
                    }
                } else if (board[y][x] == DEAD){
                    if (amountOfAliveNeighbours == 3) {
                        newBoard[y][x] = ALIVE;
                    }else{
                        newBoard[y][x] = DEAD;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        board = newBoard;
    }

    private int getAmountOfAliveNeighbours(int x, int y) {
        int neighbours = 0;
        // top left
        if (x - 1 >= 0 && y - 1 >= 0) {
            if (board[y - 1][x - 1] == ALIVE)
                neighbours++;
        }
        // top center
        if (y - 1 >= 0) {
            if (board[y - 1][x] == ALIVE)
                neighbours++;
        }
        // top right
        if (x + 1 < board[0].length && y - 1 >= 0) {
            if (board[y - 1][x + 1] == ALIVE)
                neighbours++;
        }
        // middle left
        if (x - 1 >= 0) {
            if (board[y][x - 1] == ALIVE)
                neighbours++;
        }
        // middle right
        if (x + 1 < board[0].length) {
            if (board[y][x + 1] == ALIVE)
                neighbours++;
        }
        // bottom left
        if (x - 1 >= 0 && y + 1 < board.length) {
            if (board[y + 1][x - 1] == ALIVE)
                neighbours++;
        }
        // bottom center
        if (y + 1 < board.length) {
            if (board[y + 1][x] == ALIVE)
                neighbours++;
        }
        // bottom right
        if (x + 1 < board[0].length && y + 1 < board.length) {
            if (board[y + 1][x + 1] == ALIVE)
                neighbours++;
        }
        return neighbours;
    }
```

Comment: `int[][] newBoard = board;` and `board = newBoard;` are not performing a copy of arrays, they just copy references. So they both point to the same array. Look to System.arraycopy() to really copy the data.

Comment: Also, your check for neighbours in getAmountOfAliveNeighbours()  can be significantly simplified with loops.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to copy data from board to newBoard and back, you just need to allocate memory for the newBoard, at the end you can still save the reference to it in board.

Comment: @Alex thanks this fixed the issue :D I couldn't think of a way to simplify thats why I did it the stupid way.

Comment: I added the code to calculate neighbours to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allocate the memory for the temporary board like this:

```
int[][] newBoard = new int[board.length][board[0].length];
```

I would suggest to refactor calculation of neighbours:

```
  private int getAmountOfAliveNeighbours(int x, int y) {
    int neighbours = 0;
    for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
      for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
        if ((dx !=0 || dy != 0) && isAlive(x + dx, y + dy)) {
          neighbours++;
        }
      }
    }
    return neighbours;
  }

  private boolean isAlive(int x, int y) {
    return (x >= 0) && (x < board.length) &&
        (y >= 0) && (y < board[0].length) &&
        (board[x][y] == ALIVE);
  }
```